# How to retrieve the latest state from an RxJS observable?

Tags: rxjs, observable, ngrx, angular2-observables

In this [ngrx example](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/containers/find-book-page.ts), `searchQuery$` is an RxJS `Observable`. I understand that this `Observable` emits changes when the search query string changes on the UI.

I have introduced another `Observable` called `paging$` to this control to do the paging. This `Observable` emits the page number. When the page changes, I have to make another server call to retrieve the remaining books.

When I make the call to the server when the user clicks the page, I have the page number because it comes directly from the UI, but not the search string which is already emitted by the `searchQuery$` Observable.

How can I combine `searchQuery$` and `paging$` to retrieve both the search string and the page number using RxJS?

UPDATE:

Events:

1. User types `an` in the search box.
2. The first 10 books are displayed.
3. The user now clicks the NEXT paging button.
4. The next 10 books should be displayed (after a http request with the last search string `an`).

The code from ngrx example:

```js
import 'rxjs/add/operator/let';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import * as fromRoot from '../reducers';
import * as book from '../actions/book';
import { Book } from '../models/book';

@Component({
  selector: 'bc-find-book-page',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: '
    <bc-book-search [query]="searchQuery$ | async" [searching]="loading$ | async" (search)="search($event)"></bc-book-search>
    <bc-book-preview-list [books]="books$ | async"></bc-book-preview-list>
  '
})
export class FindBookPageComponent {
  searchQuery$: Observable<string>;
  books$: Observable<Book[]>;
  loading$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
    this.searchQuery$ = store.select(fromRoot.getSearchQuery).take(1);
    this.books$ = store.select(fromRoot.getSearchResults);
    this.loading$ = store.select(fromRoot.getSearchLoading);
  }

  search(query: string) {
    this.store.dispatch(new book.SearchAction(query));
  }
}
```

Comment: The downvote is not from me, but a hint regarding your question: Please include code directly on stackoverflow, because the external code might change over time or might be taken offline or the link might break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest):

```
updateBooks$ = Observable.combineLatest(
    this.searchQuery$,
    this.paging$
).do(([searchQuery, paging]: [string, number]) => {
    ...makeServerRequest or dispatch an action here
});

updateBooks$
    // when subscribing in a component directly, don't forget to handle component-destructions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42490265/rxjs-takeuntil-angular2-components-ngondestroy
    .takeUntil(destroyed$)
    .subscribe();
```

*in case your code is identical to the ngrx-example, you will have to remove the `take(1)` from the store-select on the `searchQuery$`

Comment: Does this mean, any observable will keep it's latest state and can be retrieved as above?

Comment: Not any observable, but if you have a `select`-statement on your store it will be the case - and additionally: `combineLatest` will hold the latest state of the given observables and emit an array of all the latest states whenever one of the given observables emits data.

Comment: As I said in the original question, ```this.searchQuery$``` is not changing in the UI. Only the paging events changing. So, doesn't the value ```this.searchQuery$``` observable emit is empty rather than what the user entered on the UI? What I dont understand is there is no ```subject``` that is emitting search string for this ```observable``` to combine with.

Comment: I don't think I understand your issue - just in case you have built your example on top of the example-app, you would of course have to remove the `take(1)` after the store-select, because that would only trigger the update from the store once.

Comment: Whenever the user types something in the search-input, the store is updated with the searchQuery - if nothing was ever entered, then it is just an empty string.

Comment: I updated the question with the action sequence. I hope that can clarify my doubt.

Comment: Yes, did you test my solution yet? It should work for this case

Comment: Yes. That worked. I declared the ```updateBooks$``` in the component constructor.