# Cancelling http subscription in rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my angular app i would like to be able to cancel and http request that is make with Rxjs. The scenario:

```
isComponentAlive = true;

onSave() { 
    this.service.save(this.formValue).takeWhile(() => this.isComponentAlive).subscribe();
}

ngOnDestroy() { 
  this.isComponentAlive = false;
}
```

Than i have a cancel button which navigates to another route. I would like to cancel a pending http request, but this way is not working. I would like to do something more clear then calling unsubscribe to all my http request subscriptions

Comment: `takeWhile` cannot be used to cancel a pending HTTP request, as the predicate it takes is called [when it receives a value](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeWhile) - i.e. when the HTTP request emits a response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general there are two ways to do this.

1. **Manually unsubscribe**

   ```
   onSave() { 
       this.sub = this.service.save(this.formValue).subscribe();
   }

   ngOnDestroy() { 
       this.sub.unsubscribe();
   }
   ```

   You can also create one instance of `Subscription` class and then just add handlers to it:

   ```
   private sub = new Subscription();

   onSave() { 
       this.sub.add(this.service.save(this.formValue).subscribe());
   }

   ngOnDestroy() { 
       this.sub.unsubscribe();
   }
   ```

   This way you don't need to have multiple subscriptions and manually call `unsubscribe()` on all of them.
2. **Use an instance of `Subject` to complete the source Observable**

   ```
   private subject = new Subject();

   onSave() { 
       this.sub.add(this.service.save(this.formValue).takeUntil(subject).subscribe());
   }

   ngOnDestroy() { 
       this.subject.next();
   }
   ```

Btw, this is a very similar question to yours: [RxJS: takeUntil() Angular component's ngOnDestroy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42490265/rxjs-takeuntil-angular-components-ngondestroy/42493315#42493315)

Answer (score 1):

In order to cancel a subscription, you will need to keep a reference to it.

```
onSave() {
  this.saveSubscription = this.service.save(this.formValue).takeWhile(() => this.isComponentAlive).subscribe();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.isComponentAlive = false;
  this.saveSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

And this should do the trick :)