# observable does not subscribe

Tags: angular, angular2-observables, angular-observable

I have used behavior subject to next an observable.

**component1.ts**

```
this._service.searchText(result);
```

**service.ts**

```
    private searchSubject= new Subject<any>();

    searchText(mission: any) {
        this.searchSubject.next(mission);
  }

  search$ = this.searchSubject.asObservable();
```

**component2.ts**

```
    subscriptions: Array<Subscription> = [];
     constructor(private _service: service,) {
         tempSubscription = _service.search$.subscribe(
              (mission: any) => {
                console.log("subscribed to search");
                if (mission) {
               //Code
                }
              });
       this.subscriptions.push(tempSubscription)

      tempSubscription = _service.someOtherObservable$((event)=>{

           //Code.

         });
        this.subscriptions.push(tempSubscription)

        }
      ngOnDestroy(): void {
    for (let sub of this.subscriptions) {
      sub.unsubscribe();
  }
  }
```

If I remove  `subscription.push(tempSubscription)` after subscribing to $search then subscription work. Else nothing logs within it. Also If I take different variables for both storing output of both observable then also it works.

Note: Same observable is subscribed in other components in a similar way and it is working fine.
What am I doing wrong by pushing observables into an array and then unsubscribing?

Comment: do you intend to do `subscriptions.push(tempSubscription)` instead of `subscription.push(tempSubscription)` ?

Comment: @prady Thanks, but that was just a typo while posting it here not in actual code. Corrected it.

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45087291/unsubscribing-an-array-of-subscriptions

Comment: @Evelijn Thanks a lot. This solution worked for me.

Comment: @Simer Great, you're welcome! :)