# Angular subscribe to change of variable in another component

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscribe

I have an application that consist of 3 components and 1 service:

- app.component. This holds my navbar etc. In the navbar there is a mat-select where you can choose the customer.
- orders.component. Lists the orders of the current selected customer.
- products.component. Lists the products of the current selected customer.
- customer.service. Some functions used for customers, but also a variable with the current selected customer

**Desired state:**

- When a customer is not selected and user navigates to orders or products, no call should be made to the API.
- When a customer is selected in the navbar while the user is on the orders/products page, the API should trigger to get the orders/products for the choosen customer.
- When the customer is changed, the API should be triggered to load the new customers orders/products
- When a customer is selected and the user navgiates to orders/products, the API should be called directly to get the data

**Current state**

- Currently I have added `customerObserver: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();` to the customer.service.
- When a customer is selected in the navbar (app.components), it calls a function in customer.service which in the end will do `this.customerObserver.next(this.customer);`
- In both the orders and products components, I do this:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.customerService.customer) {
      this.loadOrders();
    }

    this.customerService.customerObserver.subscribe(customer => {
      if(customer) {
        this.loadOrders();
      }
    });
  }
```

The functionality worked fine, but I realised that as I do never unsubscribe this messes up the application totally as it creates a lot of subscribes when navigating around. I added unsubscribe in orders (see snippet below), but then when I am navigating around I get the following error: `ObjectUnsubscribedErrorImpl {message: 'object unsubscribed', name: 'ObjectUnsubscribedError'}`

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.customerService.customerObserver.unsubscribe();
  }
```

I have tried to read up on subscribe for a while now but is stuck how to proceed.. Any tips on how to arrange to achieve the desired state?

Answer (score 2):

You can emit data from the service to the components observers.

```
private customerSubject = new Subject<number>();
customerSelectedAction$ = this.customerSubject.asObservable();

products$ = this.customerSelectedAction$.pipe(
 switchMap(customerId=>this.http.get<Product[]>(`${this.url}?customerId=${customerId}`))
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log(data)),
      catchError(this.handleError)
  ));

orders$ = this.customerSelectedAction$.pipe(
 switchMap(customerId=>this.http.get<Orders[]>(`${this.url}?customerId=${customerId}`))
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log(data)),
      catchError(this.handleError)
  ));

selectedCustomerChanged(customer: Customer): void {
  this.customerSubject.next(customer.id);
}
```

After that, you subscribe to the `products$` or `orders$` observables depending on which component you are. And use the `selectedCustomerChanged(customer: Customer)` method from navbar.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, I would place all the code above in customer.service?

Comment: yes, in `CustomerService`

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the subscription in each component in a subscription array, you can look here for the best answer:
[Unsubscribing an array of subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45087291/unsubscribing-an-array-of-subscriptions)

Another tip, you can use a private BehaviorSubject (and a public asObservable prop), starting with null, so you can remove the `customerObserver: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();` altogether.
You just subscribe to that observable and load orders if the customer is not null (you can also use distinct until changed).

Comment: Hi! I will check the option to have a subscription array.
For the second option you posted. How would that fit if I want for example the orders.component to reload orders upon change of the customer while I am in the orders page?

Comment: Since you subscribe to stream of <Customer> and do next on customer change - you can just reload the orders like you did in your example.
There's actually lots of ways to do this - if you want more separation, the order component can actually subscribe to an Order service (or even better, a facade specialized for the view) which will react to customer changes