# Angular Components still listening to subscriptions after being destroyed

Tags: angular, rxjs

**Angular 5**

The issue I am having is that when I navigate away from a component, the component is still listening and acting upon service subscription updates.

My Service

```
export class GlobalVarsService {
  private selectedDepartment = new BehaviorSubject<number>(null);
  selectedDepartment$ = this.selectedDepartment.asObservable();

...
}
```

MyComponent

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.globalVarsService.selectedDepartment$.subscribe( selectDepartment => {
        this.refreshReportData();
    });
}
```

I could be 3 clicks away from `MyComponent` but if I update `selectedDepartment` then the subscription will still fire and `this.refreshReportData` will execute.  Obviously I do not want this because it's extra HTTP calls that are completely unnecessary.

I have tried implementing `onDestroy` to validate that the component destruction is happening when I navigate way and it does.  So from my perspective it appears that my destroyed component is still active and listening for subscription events.  There also is no `unsubscribe` method available on `this.globalVarsService.selectedDepartment$` so I can't put that into my `onDestroy` method either.

What do I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes,  you have to unsubscribe inside ngOnDestroy, but if you use Async Pipe, it will handle that automatically

```
import { Subscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";
private subscription: Subscription ;
ngOnInit() {
 this.subscription = this.globalVarsService.selectedDepartment$.subscribe( selectDepartment => {
    this.refreshReportData();
});
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: I read somehwere on stackoverflow that the recommended way of handling subscriptions in a component is with the takeUntil operator. I find that way also more elegant than tracking each subscription. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42490265/rxjs-takeuntil-angular-components-ngondestroy?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa