# Passing data to component using GET request

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components, get-request

How can I pass data retrieved in my service back out to a component every time a new data/URL is passed to it and loop over it with NgFor? I would like to use promises and not observables.

For clarification: Service(A) needs to pass its object to Component(B) every time the data changes and then loop over it with NgFor. Thanks in advance

here's my code:

SERVICE(A)

```
 receiveEvent(eventId){
   return fetch(eventId).then(res => res.json())
   .then((data:any) => {
     console.log(data);
 });
```

RECEIVING COMPONENT(B)

```
 requestEvent(requestUrl){
  this._clientService.receiveEvent(requestUrl)
  }
```

Comment: I assume you weren't happy with my answer using observables to the last time you asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60139675/5367916. Can I ask why you don't want to use observables? They really do fit your use case very well.

Comment: If you insist on promises, then take the advice from my answer to your previous question and look up pub/sub using promises. The pattern is probably more important to you finding a solution here than the technology is.

Comment: I was struggling to get it to work, I wanted to try a different approach with promises. Observables are a big learning curve for me.

Comment: I understand that observables are hard to learn. This is a fairly complex usage of them. I would recommend learning about them though, as they come up all the time as you use Angular more. Start off small by just creating your own subject and experimenting with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return a promise and resolve in the finally callback:

**service**

```
fetch(URL: string): Promise < any > {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.get(URL)
            .subscribe(response => {
                console.debug("response = %O", response);
                // set data locally
                this.myVariable = data[0]["myVarible"];
            }, error => {
                console.error(error);
            }, () => {  // finally
                resolve();
            })
    });
}
```

**calling component constructor**

```
this.myService.fetch(URL).then(() => {
    console.log(this.myService.myVariable);
});
```

Unless you're using websockets, you will have to poll the database frequently for new data; wrap the calling component constructor's fetch in `setInterval`