# Angular subscribe elegant

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'd like to ask about my subscribe method. I want to get my objects(employees) from firebase and do a loot of operations on my objects, like avg salaries, avg missed days... In my opinion it looks so horrible. My service void:

```
 getEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]> {
    return this.db.list<Employee>(this.Api_url).snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(response => response.map(car => this.assignKey(car))));
  }
```

And my ngOnInit:

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.subscribtion = this.mainservice.getEmployees().subscribe((emps)=> {
      this.employees = emps;
      this.workersdatas = [];
      this.educationdatas = [];
      this.checkavaragesalaries(emps);
      this.countMonthAbsences(emps, 1);
      this.countMonthSalaries(emps, 1);
      this.departments.forEach((one)=> {
        const dep = emps.filter(on => on.department.includes(one) && this.FilterEmployees(on)).length;
        this.workersdatas.push({name: one, value: dep});
      });

      this.educations.forEach((one)=> {
        const edu = emps.filter(on => on.education.includes(one)).length;
        this.educationdatas.push({name: one, value: edu});
      });

      const mynumb =this.educationdatas.map(on => on.value);
      this.mosteducation = this.educationdatas.filter(one => one.value === Math.max(...mynumb))[0].name;
    }); }
```

Should I unsubscribe() it on ngOnDestroy or that's not necessary? Is that allowed to write it like that?

Answer (score 8):

My favourite unsubscribe pattern is to use `takeUntil`. `takeUntil()` accepts an observable, and will stop the subscription when that observable emits a value.

The long-winded way to do this is emit a value in `ngOnDestroy()`.

```
destroyed = new Subject<void>();

ngOnInit(): void {
  myService.getData().pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroyed)
  ).subscribe(data => {
    // process data
  });
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.destroyed.next();
  this.destroyed.complete();
}
```

This gets quite tedious once you've done this a few times. The best solution I've seen for this (and currently use) is to set up a shared function that emits the destroyed value for you. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45709120/5367916) [Credit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@w11k/ngx-componentdestroyed)

```
import { OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

import { ReplaySubject, Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

export function componentDestroyed(component: OnDestroy): Observable<void> {
  const oldNgOnDestroy: () => void = component.ngOnDestroy;
  const destroyed: Subject<void> = new ReplaySubject<void>(1);
  component.ngOnDestroy = () => {
    oldNgOnDestroy.apply(component);
    destroyed.next(undefined);
    destroyed.complete();
  };
  return destroyed.asObservable();
}
```

It is then almost trivial to use in your component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  myService.getData().pipe(
    takeUntil(componentDestroyed(this))
  ).subscribe(data => {
    // process data
  });
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {}
```

All you have to do is implement ngOnDestroy in your component and add `takeUntil(componentDestroyed(this))` to your pipe.

Comment: I know it's a bit old post, but take a look to https://netbasal.com/automagically-unsubscribe-in-angular-4487e9853a88

Comment: @Eliseo That is a good alternative. I'm not sure I had seen the decorator way at the time of making this post. At this point I think it's a matter of preference. I personally prefer the transparency of calling a function directly, but I can definitely see why some would prefer the "Automagic" of a decorator. There's no single correct answer here :)

Answer (score 0):

Is that allowed to put every operations inside subscribe method like I did?