# Setting Component Property Within Pipe or Subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

Say I have a component and I call my api service to return me an observable of type `User[]`, emitting only one value. What way is preferred to setting my global variable?

Note: I am not using an async pipe within my html file in this example

### Using Subscribe and takeUntil

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  users: User[];
  ngUnsubscribe: Subject<unknown> = new Subject<unknown>();

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
      .subscribe(res => this.users = res);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }
}
```

### Using a Pipeable Operator with an Empty Subscribe

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  users: User[];

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers()
      .pipe(map(users => this.users = users))
      .subscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by global variable?

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu My users property (variable) in my ExampleComponent

Comment: Both will work, but assigning inside subscription is the semantically correct way. Operators like `map` are used to transform the notifications from the source observable.

Comment: @MichaelD is there another pipeable rxjs operator that would work better? The benefit of using the pipe and empty subscribe method is that I don't have to every worry about unsubscribing from my observable (as well as less code).

Comment: You can chain pipes here, the first approach is better as you are unsubscribing on destroy to avoid memory leakes, also you can chain pipe operators, best way would be to you takeUntil + tap operator (instead of map) as you are not transforming the result.

Comment: You can also avoid the unsubscribe subject part by using take(1) instead of takeUntil if your fetch operation is a one timer.

Comment: @Josh96: It doesn't matter if the subscription is empty. Calling `subscription` on an observable will anyway open a data stream and you need to handle it's unsubscription. For easier ways to handle unsubscription you could refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60223749/6513921

Answer (score 0):

```
this.userService
            .getUser()
            .pipe(take(1))
            .subscribe((user) => {
                this.userList = user;
            });
```

Or you can use in async pipe in HTML like this

```
user$|async
```