# Async / await on ngOninit()

Tags: angular, http, asynchronous

I'm trying to use the `async`/`await` (for the first time) and I can't wrap my head around it.

What am I doing wrong here:

**`tree.component.ts`**

```
export class TreeComponent implements OnInit {

  private routeSub: any;
  acronym: string;
  flare: any[];

  constructor(
    private location: Location,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private http: HttpClient,
        private router: Router,
        private fileTreeService: FileTreeService
  ) {


  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(
        params => {
            this.acronym = params.name
            this.fileTreeService.getFileTree(params.name).subscribe(item => {
                this.flare = item;

            });
        });
```

**filetree.service.ts**

```
export class FileTreeService {

    res: any;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }



    async getFileTree(acronym) {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders()
        this.res = await this.http.get<any>(`${IP}/filetree/tree/`, { headers });
        return this.res;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error "Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise'" in filetree.component.ts. I've reached the end of the road here, so I'm reaching out to you guys. Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Thanks for the help, it kinda worked but it didn't do what I was trying to achive. Isn't supposed to wait for the result before continue executing the code?

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(async (params) => {
            this.acronym = params.name
            this.flare = await this.fileTreeService.getFileTree(params.name).toPromise();
            console.log("flare = ", this.flare);
        });

    let test = this.flare;
    console.log("test = ", test);
}
```

root is declared before flare has been given a value. This what my browser console spits out.

```
test =  undefined
flare =  {name: "data", children: Array(81)}
```

Comment: Async functions are expected to return a promise. Subscribe is for observables usually. getFileTree doesn't return an observable

Comment: I see.. how do I return a promise instead? Guess it's more complicated than I first thought.

Comment: You're already returning a promise. Instead of `subscribe` use `then` in `ngOnInit`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

async/await work on promise so in case you use httpClinet methods you need to convert the return value from Observable to promise by `toPromise` method

*filetree.service.ts*

```js
export class FileTreeService {
    res: any;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getFileTree(acronym) {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders()
        // return an observable 
        return  this.http.get<any>(`${IP}/filetree/tree/`, { headers })    
   }
}
```

*component*

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
      //  mark the upper function with async
      this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(async (params) => {  
        this.acronym = params.name;
        //  now we can use await but we need to convert the observable to promise 
        this.flare = await this.fileTreeService.getFileTree(params.name).toPromise();
        });
}
```

you can read in depth tutorial *[here](https://javascript.info/async-await)*

**Updated**

we can mark ngOnInit with async and use await for all observances after we convert theme to promise in that case we will no longer to use subscribe.

```js
  //  mark the upper function with async
  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    //  now we can use await but we need to convert the observable to promise 
    this.acronym = (await this.route.params.toPromise()).name;
    this.flare = await this.fileTreeService.getFileTree(this.acronym).toPromise();
    let test = this.flare;  // => {name: "data", children: Array(81)}
    console.log("test = ", test); // => {name: "data", children: Array(81)}

  }
```

Comment: I'm trying to follow your lead here, but I'm probably missing something here. It still doesn't wait for the return value before proceeding. Added an update in my post.

Comment: I cannot say that this is wrong: ngOnInit(): void {
      //  mark the upper function with async
      this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(async (params) => {  
        this.acronym = params.name;
        //  now we can use await but we need to convert the observable to promise 
        this.flare = await this.fileTreeService.getFileTree(params.name).toPromise();
        });
} But i can tell you for sure that you can do a subscribe inside of subscribe, so you can just subscribe to the fileTreeService and do there what you want.

Comment: @Erik there no wrong of using async/await to prevent nested subscription I will update my answer to  use await for all observables in ngOnInit

Comment: @klabbaparn check my updated answer where I use await for all observables

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to async/reactive programming, I wouldn't recommend you to mix promises and observables. Since you're using Angular HttpClient Module, which returns an observble for an HTTP request, we could stick only with it.

So you could return the HTTP request directly without converting it to a promise. Sidenote: observables also provide much more control on the data flow and data transform operators compared to promises.

Service

```js
export class FileTreeService {
  res: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getFileTree(acronym): Observable<any> {      // <-- `http.get()` returns an observable
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    return this.http.get<any>(`${IP}/filetree/tree/`, { headers });
  }
}
```

Additionally, now you have a child observable from `this.fileTreeService.getFileTree()` function that depends on the notification from another observable `this.route.params`.

In such cases instead of having multiple inner subscriptions like you're doing, you could use RxJS higher order mapping operator like [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) to map from one observable to another. Now 2 different data streams from your code is reduced to one single stream. Lesser the streams - lesser the potential memory leaks.

Component

```js
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class TreeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private routeSub: any;
  acronym: string;
  flare: any[];
  complete$ = new Subject<any>();     // <-- use to close open subscriptions

  constructor(
    private location: Location,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private http: HttpClient,
        private router: Router,
        private fileTreeService: FileTreeService
  ) { }
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.routeSub = this.route.params.pipe(
      switchMap(params => {           // <-- use `switchMap` to map from one observable to another
        this.acronym = params.name;
        return this.fileTreeService.getFileTree(params.name);
      }),
      takeUntil(this.complete$)       // <-- close the subscription when `this.complete$` emits
    ).subscribe(
      item => {
        this.flare = item;
        console.log(this.flare);      // <-- correct log: will print the value of `this.flare`
      },
      error => {
        // always good practice to handle errors from HTTP requests
      }
    );

    console.log(this.flare);          // <-- wrong log: will print `undefined`
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.complete$.next();            // <-- close open subscriptions
  }
}
```

Also remember, since the `this.flare` variable is assigned asynchronously, all statements that depend on it must be inside the subscription. It is illustrated in the code above using the different `console.log()` statements. The one inside subscription will print the correct value whereas the one outside the subscription will wrongfully print either undefined or older value held by the `this.flare`.

I've also used RxJS [`takeUntil`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/takeUntil) operator to close open subscriptions in the `ngOnDestory()` hook. You could find more details about it and other easier method of handling unsubscriptions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60223749/6513921).

Comment:  I enjoy reading you answer it's rxjs magic  and it very helpful

Comment: you did a great job with comments 

Comment: wow, thanks for the throughout answer. I'm gonna take some time to digest all of this. Was quite a lot more than I had anticipated, heh.