# Move takeUntil rxjs operator to separate method

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, extension-methods

I have `BaseComponent` class in my Angular app, which implements `destroy$: Subject<void>` for observables. Every time I subscribe to service, I'm doing:

```
this.myService.loadData()
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
    .subscribe(data => this.userData = data);
```

I want to avoid writing `.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))` everywhere and I'm wondering, is there any way to create extension method for observable and handle `takeUntil` there? for example to move `.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))` to my custom method `ifAlive` and make it look like this:

```
this.myService.loadData()
    .isAlive()
    .subscribe(...);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There are other ways. Refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60223749/6513921

Comment: This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41177163/9423231) covers some options like [until-destroy](https://github.com/ngneat/until-destroy).

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is an `async` pipe. Basically you allow angular to do the subscription and unsubscription for you

You simply assign the resulting observable to a variable

In your **ts** file

```typescript
data$ = this.myService.loadData()
```

and in your **html** simply wrap your content with `*ngIf='data$ | async as data'`

```html
<ng-container *ngIf='data$ | async as data'>

</ng-container>
```

With the above, Angular will handle the subscription and your code is both easy to read, test and debug

Comment: The subtle yet important difference being that if you use this multiple times, you'll end up making your network requests multiple times, and thus a proper replacement would be to multicast this observable.

Comment: Good point, the `shareReplay` operator will solve this.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**. You could certainly abstract this as you said.

However, the following **already unsubscribe for us**:

- **async pipe**
- **http client requests** if it's solely a network request and not a new subscription as a callback

Additionally, from an angular perspective, it's best to unsubscribe on `ngOnDestroy`, as this is when the component lifecycle ends. Not to say you weren't planning on this, but it could make your abstraction a lot of more complex. Something to consider.

For example, you would still have to store your subscriptions (when in a component, as services won't use `ngOnDestroy`) and then unsubscribe using your abstraction, which defeats the purpose of the abstraction, because you still have to add some boilerplate code.

**So in short**, the abstraction is a good idea for services, but for components, it's a lot more complex and I would try to use the async pipe and local unsubscribing as a preferred approach.