# how to call method when I moved from login component to home component Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-ui-router

So in my login component, I generate one token that gives me access to Tablaue dashboard from the angular app

so when I log in at that time only the home component method should call/run. but when I refresh the home page(component) should not run/call that method

Example

```
login-page.component.ts
public getToken(){
// i received token here
// then i move to the home page component
// saving token into the session
this.router.navigate(["/home"]);

}

home-page.component.ts
public  tokenAccess(){
// this method will be run only once when I come from the login page.
// should not run when the page is refreshed or reloaded
}
```

Thank you

Comment: How do you go from login-page to home-page? Using Angular router or some other means?

Comment: this.router.navigate(["/home"]);

Answer (score 1):

Expanding from your comment, you could send a query parameter in the route to denote if the token has indeed been fetched in the login-page component.

**login-page.component.ts**

```js
public getToken(){
  this.router.navigate(["/home"], { queryParams: { token: true }});
}
```

The resulting routing URL would be of the form

```
http://example/home?token=true
```

The query parameter `token` would only be present when routed from the login-page component and not on page refresh or reload.

**home-page.component.ts**

```js
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private _actRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this._actRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    if (params['token']) {      // <-- condition would fail on page refresh/reload
      this.tokenAccess();
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: let me try this out

Comment: condition is not getting failed while page refresh and reload :/

Comment: That's right. The parameter would be persisted if it was already available. You could look into this workaround using `sessionStorage`. Variable stored in `sessionStorage` are not persisted b/n page refresh/reload.

Comment: After subscribing can we destroy this subscribe?

Comment: Theoretically you could, but I'd be good practice to close the subscription in the `ngOnDestroy()` hook.

Comment: ngOnDestroy() {
  
    this._actRoute.queryParams;
} is it right?

Comment: @ShreeBatale: No you either need to use `unsubscribe` or see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60223749/6513921