# nothing happens when the observable is completed in my angular component

Tags: angular, rxjs-observables, angular-observable

In my Angular component, I have this

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.route.paramMap
.pipe(
  tap(item=>console.log(item))
)
.subscribe(
  params => {
    const proyectoId = params.get('proyectoId');
    this.empleadoId = +params.get('empleadoId');
  }
  ,err=>console.log(err)
  ,()=>{
    console.log('Hola');
  }
);
```

}

But when I debug I don't see the console.log

[image: log]

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observable returned from Angular's [`ActivatedRoute#paramMap`](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#paramMap) is perpetual unless closed explicitly. If you wish to use only the first emission (in most ideal cases it should be enough for `paramMap`), you could pipe in a `take(1)`. It would close the observable after it's first emission.

```js
this.route.paramMap.pipe(
  take(1)
  tap(item => console.log(item)),
).subscribe(
  ...
);
```

That said, if you couldn't use `take(1)`, it's always good practice to close such observables in the component's `ngOnDestroy()` hook. It'd ensure there are no memory leaks from open observables after the component is closed. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60223749/6513921) for more info.