# Angular 9 return Observable from an Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, pipe, observable

I am looking for a way to return an Observable from another Observable. I found that you can do that using **pipe** and **map** operators, but it does not seem to be working for me. What am I doing wrong ?

I am using **Angular 9.1.12** and **rxjs ~6.5.4**.

Example:
Service1

```js
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

export class Service1 {

  test(): Observable<string> {
      console.log(1);
      return of('hey');
  }
}
```

Service2

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class Service2 {

  constructor(private service1: Service1) {}

  test(): Observable<string> {
    return this.service1.test().pipe(
      map((value: string) => {
        console.log(2);
        return value;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Component

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service2: Service2) {}

  test(): Observable<void> {
    return this.service2.test().pipe(
      map((value: string) => {
        console.log(3);
      }));
    }
  }
}
```

The console will only output `1`.

Comment: Where and how are you subscribing?

Comment: Oh my, I added .subscribe() in component call and it works now, great. You can post an answer and I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's reasonable cause you never subscribe to the `observables` so they never actual emitted or run.

You should subscribe on the component like this.

```
this.test().subscribe();
```

I have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-brjopz?file=src/app/app.component.ts) to play around.

*PS: Be aware that you have to unsubscribe when needed also. If you are not familiar with these concepts I suggest you to read [that](https://netbasal.com/when-to-unsubscribe-in-angular-d61c6b21bad3) article.*

Answer (score 1):

Just as functions only run the code inside when you invoke them, `Observables` only run their code when you you subscribe to them.

You see `1` output because you invoke `this.service1.test()`.

You don't see `2` or `3` because you never subscribe to those `Observables`.

```
export class Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service2: Service2) {}

  test(): void {
    this.service2.test().pipe(
      map(_ => console.log(3))
    ).subscribe();
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of observables: hot and cold. I am not going into hot observables since it doesn't have anything to do with the question. You could find more information [here](https://leecampbell.com/2010/08/19/rx-part-7-hot-and-cold-observables/)

Cold observables - as the name implies - do not start processing it's inner statements until it is subscribed to. So in this case when you subscribe in the component, it would trigger all the observables upto to the inner most `of('hey')`.

```js
export class Component implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service2: Service2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.test().subscribe();
  }

  test(): Observable<void> {
    return this.service2.test().pipe(
      tap((value: string) => console.log(value))
    );
  }
}
```

One more thing to note here, you were using `map` operator in the component without a return statement. In that case, it would return `undefined`. `map` is generally used to transform the incoming statements. `tap` operator would be a better fit here. It's used to perform side-effects.

#### Unsubscribe

Futhermore, open subscriptions do not close unless an error is emitted or explicitly completed. So it's always a good idea to close open subscriptions after they are used.

Eg. in Angular it's common practice to close it in the `ngOnDestroy` hook so that it's closed when the component is closed.

```js
export class Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  sub: Subscription;

  constructor(private service2: Service2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.test().subscribe();
  }

  test(): Observable<void> {
    return this.service2.test().pipe(
      tap((value: string) => console.log(value))
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (!!this.sub)
      this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

There are more elegant ways to close open subscriptions. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60223749/6513921