# Subscribe to params and use observable in template with async

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I want to get the profile id from the current url. I am doing something like

```
opaProfileId$ = this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe((params) => +params.get('opaProfileId'));
```

then in template I want to compare it with a number like

```
<tr [ngClass]="{ 'highlight-row': profile.id === opaProfileId$ | async as number }" *ngFor="let profile of data">
```

but it throws error. Any ideas how to do it with observable?

Comment: Don't subscribe, that is what the `async` pipe does for you (and unsubscribes) Now you are assigning a subscription to `opaProfileId$.`

Comment: Just saying `it throws error` without providing the error is not very helpful. It's like saying "It doesn't work"

Answer (score 3):

You *cannot* combine subscription in component and `async` pipe in template.

#### Subscription in component controller

You either subscribe in the component controller or use `async` in template. While subscribing in controllers, it'd serve you better to close the subscription when the component is closed. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60223749/6513921) for more info.

```js
opaProfileId: number;

this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe((params) => 
  this.opaProfileId = +params.get('opaProfileId')
);
```

```html
<tr [ngClass]="{ 'highlight-row': profile.id === opaProfileId }" *ngFor="let profile of data">
```

#### `async` pipe

While using `async` pipe, you'd need to use the RxJS `map` operator for fetching the query param and type casting. While using `async`, explicitly closing the subscription isn't necessary. `async` pipe takes care of it.

```js
opaProfileId$: Observable<number>;

this.opaProfileId$ = this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.pipe(
  map((params) => +params.get('opaProfileId'))
);
```

```html
<tr [ngClass]="{ 'highlight-row': profile.id === (opaProfileId$ | async) }" *ngFor="let profile of data">
```