# Angular observable not updating automatically

Tags: angular, observable, behaviorsubject

I have a service that I pass a value to so the value is available to all components that need it:

```
  setAnalysisStatus(statuses: AsyncAnalysis[]) {
    this.analysisStatus.next(statuses);
  }
```

I have a component that's shown using a button click. The component that displays calls another method to subscribe to `analysisStatus`

```
  getAnalysisStatus(): Observable<AsyncAnalysis[]> {
    return this.analysisStatus.asObservable();
  }
```

The component subscribes like this:

```
ngOnInit(){
this.changeGroupService.getAnalysisStatus()
.subscribe(result => {
  result.forEach(item => {
    this.changeGroupStatus.forEach((changeGroup, index) => {
      if (item.changeGroupId === changeGroup.id) {
        this.changeGroupStatus[index].name = this.changeGroupStatus[index].name;
        this.changeGroupStatus[index].status = item.status;
      }
    });
  });
});
}
```

When I trigger that component it shows the current state of `analysisStatus`. However, when the state of that changes, the component doesn't update. If I close then reopen that component it shows the new state. I need it to display the state and update when the state of `analysisStatus` changes.

`analysisStatus` is being set like this:

`analysisStatus = new BehaviorSubject<AsyncAnalysis[]>([]);`

My assumption is subscirbing via `this.changeGroupService.getAnalysisStatus()` should looks for update the values in `this.changeGroupStatus`. Am I missing something?

EDIT ---

So checking `this.changeGroupService.getAnalysisStatus()` in my `ngOnInit` I can see the value for `result` is, in fact, updating as needed but the template doesn't update to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the value rendered in the template does not directly depend on the value from the observable. Additionally the variable `changeGroupStatus` isn't assigned new values. Only few properties of it is changed. Angular might not detect the partial changes. In these circumstances, you could try to manually trigger change detection using [`ChangeDetectorRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef). Try the following

```js
import { pipe, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

destroyed = new Subject<void>();

ngOnInit(){
  this.changeGroupService.getAnalysisStatus().pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroyed)
  ).subscribe(result => {
      result.forEach(item => {
        this.changeGroupStatus.forEach((changeGroup, index) => {
          if (item.changeGroupId === changeGroup.id) {
            this.changeGroupStatus[index].name = this.changeGroupStatus[index].name;
            this.changeGroupStatus[index].status = item.status;
          }
        });
      });
      this.cdr.detectChanges();           // <-- trigger change detection here
    });
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.destroyed.next();
  this.destroyed.complete();
}
```

**Update**

You could pipe in the `takeUntil` operator with an observable (that'll be completed in the `ngOnDestroy` hook) to avoid memory leak issues. But it could get tedious when there are multiple subscriptions in multiple components. There is a better solution for this issue I saw here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45709120/6513921.

Comment: Excuse me, but calling `detectChanges` in a nested loop certainly will affect the performance and may have unexpected effects. Consider moving to outside of the loops to call a single time. Another thing that I haven't tested it, but I believe that if you recreate the array using `map` or `reduce` instead of mutating it with `forEach` you wouldn’t even need to use `ChangeDetectorRef`.

Comment: @developer033: That's a valid point. I've modified the code. I am too not sure if using `map`/`reduce` would trigger the default change detection. But that's a good idea.

Comment: Be sure that you destroy the subscription after leaving the component otherwise you will have a memory leak.