# Angular - would observables benefit me in a basic HTTP POST request vs promises?

Tags: angular, http, nativescript, rxjs-observables

I'm writing an app with Angular 8. I'm kind of new to the framework coming from AngularJS. I have a lot of experience with Promises.

I have HTTP requests to my backend API. These are just GET & POST calls as there aren't any WebSockets in our Delphi backend. I have successfully called out backend API and used promises.

My code calls the backend API to get a string value that I want to display to the user.

I'm wondering how I can refactor my code to use Observables and if there is any benefit in doing so?

Service

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ILicenseInfo } from './ilicense-info';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AboutService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    public getVersionNumber() {

        const endpoint: string = 'myEndpoint';

        const params = {
            password: 'yes'
        };

        return this.http.post<ILicenseInfo>(endpoint, params)
            .toPromise()
            .then((response: ILicenseInfo) => {
                return response.versionNumberField;
            });

    }

}
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Constants } from '../../../../app/core/constants/constants.service';
import { AboutService } from './about.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'ns-about',
    templateUrl: './about.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {

    public version: string;

    constructor(private aboutService: AboutService) { }

    public ngOnInit(): void {

        this.aboutService.getVersionNumber().then((response: string) => {
            this.version = response;
        });

    }

}
```

Template

```
<FlexboxLayout>

    <FlexboxLayout>
        <Label text="Version:"></Label>
        <Label text="{{version}}"></Label>
    </FlexboxLayout>

</FlexboxLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RxJS provides many [operators](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators) and methods to modify and control the data flow from the source obsevable. More detailed list [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api).

Eg.

Combine two requests

```js
forkJoin([this.http.get('url'), this.http.post('url', '')]).subscribe
  resposne => {
    // resonse[0] - GET request response
    // resonse[1] - POST request response
  },
  error => {
  }
);
```

Pipe a response from one call as input to another request

```js
this.http.get('url').pipe(
  switchMap(getResponse => {
    return this.http.post('url', getResponse)
  }
).subscribe(
  response => { },
  error => { }
);
```

These are some of the most mundane advantages. RxJS would be more useful when multiple co-dependent observables need to handled.

---

In your case you could pipe in the [`map`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) operator to return the `versionNumberField` property from the response.

```js
return this.http.post<ILicenseInfo>(endpoint, params).pipe(
  map(response: ILicenseInfo => response.versionNumberField)
);
```

You could then subscribe to it the component to retrieve the emitted values

```js
public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.aboutService.getVersionNumber().subscribe(
    (response: string) => {
      this.version = response;
    }
  );
}
```

---

#### Potential memory leaks

With the observables, there comes a risk of potential memory leaks from non-closed subscriptions. The Angular HTTP client has a built-in unsubscription mechanism, but that too can fail. So it is always better to close the subscription in the component (usually in the `ngOnDestroy()` hook).

```js
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

httpSubscription: Subscription;

public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.httpSubscription = this.aboutService.getVersionNumber().subscribe(
    (response: string) => {
      this.version = response;
    }
  );
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  if (this.httpSubscription) {
    this.httpSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

There is also an elegant way of handling unsubscription using RxJS [`takeUntil`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/takeUntil) operator.

```js
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

closed = new Subject<void>();

public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.httpSubscription = this.aboutService.getVersionNumber().pipe(
    takeUntil(this.closed)
  ).subscribe(
    (response: string) => {
      this.version = response;
    }
  );
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.closed.next();
  this.closed.complete();
}
```

So the susbcription will be active until the `closed` observable is open.

But both these methods can get tedious very quick if you're handling multiple observables in multiple components. There is a clever workaround for this sourced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45709120/6513921).

First create the following export function

```js
// Based on https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-rx-componentdestroyed
// Source credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45709120/6513921

import { OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ReplaySubject, Observable } from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';

export function componentDestroyed(component: OnDestroy): Observable<void> {
  const oldNgOnDestroy = component.ngOnDestroy;
  const destroyed$ = new ReplaySubject<void>(1);
  component.ngOnDestroy = () => {
    oldNgOnDestroy.apply(component);
    destroyed$.next(undefined);
    destroyed$.complete();
  };
  return destroyed$.asObservable();
}
```

Now all there is to do is import the function, implement `ngOnDestroy` hook in the component and pipe in `takeUntil(componentDestroyed(this)` to the source observable.

```js
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.httpSubscription = this.aboutService.getVersionNumber().pipe(
    takeUntil(componentDestroyed(this))       // <-- pipe in the function here
  ).subscribe(
    (response: string) => {
      this.version = response;
    }
  );
}

ngOnDestroy() { }      // <-- should be implemented
```

---

#### Update: [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe

The `async` pipe can also be used to retrieve values asynchronously. It works with both observables and promises. When used with observables, it makes sure the subscription is always closed when the component is destroyed without any modifications in the controller.

Controller

```js
version$: Observable<any>;

public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.version$ = this.aboutService.getVersionNumber();
}
```

Template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(version$ | async) as version">
  Version is {{ version }}
  <ng-container *ngIf="version > 5">
    It is already the latest version available.
  <ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

<sup>Variable `version$` is named with the common convention of suffixing a dollar sign to `Observable` types.</sup>

Comment: How about the async pipe?

Comment: @user1261710: Overlooked it. I've updated the answer.