Slow destroy component with a lot of elements
I have problem with changing components when I have 1000+ rows in form. When I have this big data in component and trying to change to other component is very slow.I know it has time to delete all elements from the DOM tree but is there any solution to destroy everything with onDestroy function for example which will help me to optimize the speed.
EDIT:
I use virtual scroll to show my elements with paginations with 10 elements by default and with option to show 1k. When I try with the code below and with 1k rows, more especially with itemSize="60", it will show me only around 100 and a lot of white space, but if I change it to itemSize="1" shows me all elements, but then the performance is really slow (which is normally because it loads all 1k rows at once). So I have hard time with this.
        <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport #scrollViewport itemSize="60" minBufferPx="600" maxBufferPx="6000"
          headerHeight="60" height="560px">
          <div formArrayName="mainItemInfo"
            *cdkVirtualFor="let row of form.get('mainItemInfo')['controls']; let i = index; trackBy: tracker;">

So maybe if I use virtual scroll properly, it will optimize first my load time and when destroying all DOM elements also.

Removing thousands of elements from the DOM takes time. Why do you even need to render them all at the same time? If you have performance issues you should implement something like a virtual scroll which only renders the elements which are visible.

Do you have events assigned directly to your rows? Consider assigning them to the entire container instead. This pattern is called event delegation.

I think that's what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42490265/rxjs-takeuntil-angular-components-ngondestroy

@JSONDerulo I have paginated rows with 10 rows by default but i need to implement with option to show 20/50/100/1000 elements. I use cdk virtual scroll but i think my approach is wrong because when I change the itemSize property it shows only 100 elements but i need to show 1k and a lot of white space.

I think that you are using an *ngFor, you can try use the TrackBy.
For example:
<div *ngFor="let item of items; trackBy: trackByFn">
</div>

trackByFn(index: number, item: any): number {
  return item.id; // any unique identifier
}


yes, thank you, I am using ngFor/cdkVirtualFor to be more accurate, also I have this trackBy function but the performance is the same. I think something in cdk virtual scroll is my problem.

ok, are you using  ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush strategy?

No, i will read about it and think about how to implement it. Thank you
